# Removing Strings using Regex issues

Tags: java, json, regex

I'm trying to use the StringUtils.removeAll method to delete parts of a string and keep the other parts:

```
String locations = [{"code":"b","name":"Beavercreek"},{"code":"bj","name":"Beavercreek Juvenile"},...]
```

Here is my regex

```
StringUtils.removeAll(result.get("locations").toString(),"\\{\"code\":,\"name\":^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$\"\"\\}");
```

It doesn't remove anything, I can't get the regex correct?

Comment: What are you trying to remove? Why your regex contains `^` and `$` (these represent start of end of string, so using them in the middle of regex doesn't make much sense).

Comment: Also why are you using regex instead of proper JSON parser which would let you convert this string to JSON object which you can modify the way you want?

Comment: `,\"name\":\"[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*?\"` if you want to remove `name:value`;`\"code\":\"[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*?\",` if you want to remove `code:value`. But I would take @Pshemo's suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the string your trying to parse is JSON so I would recommend using a JSON parser. For completeness however, I'll give you a solution using a regex as well.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String locations = "[{\"code\":\"b\",\"name\":\"Beavercreek\"},{\"code\":\"bj\",\"name\":\"Beavercreek Juvenile\"}]";

    // Parsing Using a JSON Parser (Recommended)
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Model[] modelArray = jsonMapper.readValue(locations, Model[].class);

    for(Model model : modelArray) {
        System.out.println(model.toString());
    }

    // Parsing Using String.replaceAll with regex
    locations = locations.replaceAll("\\{\"code\":", "");
    locations = locations.replaceAll("\"name\":", "");

    System.out.println(locations.replaceAll("\\}", ""));
}

static class Model {
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public Model() { }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s, %s", code, name);
    }
}
}
```

Output:

```
// JSON Parsing
b, Beavercreek
bj, Beavercreek Juvenile
// REGEX Parsing
["b","Beavercreek","bj","Beavercreek Juvenile"]
```